# OpenUI5 ComboBox - How to set a default key/value

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

how does one set a default value for a combobox in OpenUI5?
I tried the **onAfterRendering** method to dynamically set the key as well but nothing happens. I would gladly appreciate your help :)

**XML View code:**

```
<ComboBox id="GenderBox" type="Unstyled"
               maxWidth="8rem"
               items="{path: 'gender>/'}"
               selectionChange="changeGender">
               <core:Item key="{gender>val}" text="{gender>val}" />
</ComboBox>
```

**Javascript code**

```
onAfterRendering: function(){
   var codebox = this.oView.byId("GenderBox");
   codebox.setSelectedKey("Male");
}
```

**More Javascript code**

```
var oView = this.getView();  
var oData = [];

oData[0] = {"val": "Female"};
oView.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData),"gender");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supose you mean using the property "selectedKey" as follows:

```
<ComboBox id="GenderBox" type="Unstyled"
               selectedKey="defaultSelectedKey"
               maxWidth="8rem"
               items="{path: 'gender>/'}"
               selectionChange="changeGender">
               <core:Item key="{gender>val}" text="{gender>val}" />
</ComboBox>
```

Where "defaultSelectedKey" must be the "val" of your model "gender" that you want to display as default.

You can check all properties, aggregations and so of UI5 components here:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ComboBox

Comment: What exactly did you try? Because I'm using the same code and it's working. Can you show us the gender json data and the binding of the property "selectedKey"?

Comment: @Gerald, apologies for that your solution works. My noticed my problem was the expression binding. All is good now